# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(object1)') during setstate

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to setstate in my react native component but I am continuously getting the error `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(object1)')`. It is a simple string state but i am contantly getting this error and i have no clue why this is happening. Below is the code for which it is throwing the error

```
const [authtoken, setAuthtoken] = useState('');
const [roomname, setRoomname] = useState('');
const [userid, setuserid] = useState('');
        fetch("", {
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              "Authorization": ""
            },
            "body": ""
          })
          .then(async response1 => {
            console.log(response1);
            var partres=await response1.json();
            console.log(partres.data.authResponse.id);
            ##Commenting these lines make the error go away
             setuserid(partres.data.authResponse.id);
             setAuthtoken(partres.data.authResponse.authToken);
            ##
            setRoomname(res.data.meeting.roomName);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
          });
```

Also, the response I get is not null. It is a string value that I did console log but the error refuses to go away. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which line throws this error? Show the full error stack

Comment: Solved it. Turns out is was an error with the package component i was using.